# Function is supposed to echo a string but it's not, no error either

Tags: php, function, oop

This function is supposed to output the message "You are an admin" in case the user is an admin, but it's not showing anything. No errors either.

The function is part of User() class.

Class function:

```
public function hasPermission($key) {
        $group = $this->_db->get('groups', array('id', '=', $this->data()->group));

        if($group->count()) {
            $permissions = json_decode($group->first()->permissions, true);

            if($permissions[$key] == true) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
}
```

Index.php output code

```
<p><?php
              if(Session::exists('home')) {
                 echo '<p>' . Session::flash('home') . '</p>';
             }
             $user = new User();
             if($user->isLoggedIn()) {
                 echo 'You are logged in! <a href="#">' . escape($user->data()-username) . '</a> <a href="logout.php"><small>Logout</small></a>';
              ?>
             <p>
                 <?php
                 if($user->hasPermission('admin')) {
                     echo 'You are an admin!';
                 }
                 ?>
             </p>
             <?php } else {
                 echo 'You need to <a href="login.php">login</a> or <a href="register.php">register</a>.';
             }
?></p>
```

EDIT: the user I am logging in with IS an admin. I can provide database structure if needed.

Comment: What's the value of `$permissions` - can you please do a `print_r` of that?

Comment: escape($user->data()-username) error on this line?

Comment: The code is on my home laptop, can't test it now. But basically $permissions is supposed to return the content of "permissions"" field in "groups" table of the current user who is logged in.

Comment: Thank you Class for pointing it out. Yes, that is a syntax error, weird it wasn't showing any. I will fix it. It should be $user->data()->username

Comment: Can you them provide the content of "permissions", as that is the condition to return true, based on the key.

Comment: print_r($permissions = json_decode($group->first()->permissions, true));
did not return anything, no errors either. This is the content of "permissions" field in the "groups" table.
{
"admin": 1
"moderator": 1
}

Comment: "did not return anything" - therefore the `if($permissions[$key] == true)` will never be true.

Comment: I see. So what could be the problem? I triple checked my function and output code, all seems correct.

Comment: It could be the `json_decode` failing, or `$group->first()->permissions` failing to return anything. Quadruple check those ;)